# Dynamically create the output Filename in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I have a simple pipeline that picks up data from SQL Server and drops the data into Azure Blob storage. I want to dynamically name the filename by appending today's date to the filename. What is the best way to do that?

[image]

I have been looking at the Expression builder, but I am not sure if that is where I should be looking.

The scenario is something like this: Once a week this pipeline will fire and grab a week's worth of data (as an example) and write that to Azure blob. Each file written should be uniquely names, so I would like to just name it something simple like "blah-20231120" for example.

Seems simple, I'm just not an expert in ADF.

I looked at Expressions, but at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Can you show some of what you've already done? Are you trying to write a specific format? Are you already writing but not getting the filename you want?

Comment: Hi Joel, my apologies, I thought I had attached it. I updated the original post to add an image. It is a simple csv file. Just want to append a date to the filename. Super simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can parameterize your file name via pipeline expressions for dynamic values. You can try @concat('blah-',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyymmdd'), '. csv')            For different types of date format type, you can use formatDateTime function